# Mocking DB/API for testing Django APIs

Tags: django-rest-framework, pytest-django

I have a Django API application. I want to write unit tests but do not want to hit the live URL or live database. How can I mock it?

Comment: While testing, Django creating a *temporary database*. So it won't hit ***live DB***

Comment: I have called a POST request. It creates entry in the actual database. My understanding is that it should create a test database and create POST data and destroy after the test. There should not be any entry in the actual database at all. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Is there a way we can verify that my test is creating a test database at all?